# VBA Excel Macro takes VERY long time to run

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a Macro and it worked great for a while but then it started to run VERY slow. It takes about 10 minutes to run when before, it would run in about 30 seconds. How do I get it to run quick again? I'm not exactly sure why its running slow now.

Basically, it changes some formatting on the sheet, moves some fields around on my pivot table, selects each shift and prints them out, then returns the sheet back to the original format.

```
Sub PostSchedule()
'
' PostSchedule Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_1_Sun").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_2_Mon").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_3_Tue").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_4_Wed").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_5_Thu").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_6_Fri").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_7_Sat").ClearManualFilter
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Shift")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .position = 6
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Trainer")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .position = 7
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("1 Sun")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .position = 8
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("2 Mon")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .position = 9
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("3 Tue")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .position = 10
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("4 Wed")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .position = 11
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("5 Thu")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .position = 12
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("6 Fri")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .position = 13
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("7 Sat")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .position = 14
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("LOA").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Present").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = "&""-,Bold""&18&U&K02-045????&U&K09+000 Crew Sheet"
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = "&D"
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = "&P of &N"
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
        .SlicerItems("12:00:00 AM").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
        .SlicerItems("12:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 AM").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("1:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
        .SlicerItems("12:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1:30:00 AM").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
        .SlicerItems("12:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1:30:00 AM").Selected = Falsee
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 AM").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("8:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
        .SlicerItems("12:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1:30:00 AM").Selected = Falsee
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:00:00 AM").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("8:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
        .SlicerItems("12:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1:30:00 AM").Selected = Falsee
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:30:00 AM").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("10:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
        .SlicerItems("12:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1:30:00 AM").Selected = Falsee
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10:00:00 AM").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
        .SlicerItems("12:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1:30:00 AM").Selected = Falsee
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 AM").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
        .SlicerItems("12:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1:30:00 AM").Selected = Falsee
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 AM").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
        .SlicerItems("12:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1:30:00 AM").Selected = Falsee
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 PM").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("3:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
        .SlicerItems("12:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1:30:00 AM").Selected = Falsee
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3:00:00 PM").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
        .SlicerItems("12:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1:30:00 AM").Selected = Falsee
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 PM").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
        .SlicerItems("12:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1:30:00 AM").Selected = Falsee
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 PM").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
        .SlicerItems("12:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1:30:00 AM").Selected = Falsee
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 AM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12:30:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:00:00 PM").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11:30:00 PM").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift").ClearManualFilter
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("1 Sun")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .position = 6
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("1 Sun").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("2 Mon").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("4 Wed").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("5 Thu").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("6 Fri").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("7 Sat").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("3 Tue").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Trainer")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .position = 3
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("LOA")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .position = 7
    End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("1 Sun")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .position = 8
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Present")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .position = 9
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = "&""-,Bold""&18&U&K02-045????&U&K09+000 Crew Sheet"
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = "&D"
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = "&P of &N"
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_1_Sun")
        .SlicerItems("6am").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("off").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("x").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("6th").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("5th").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("PTO").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you reproduce the macro steps manually does it take the same time?

Comment: If manually means clicking the little play button in the debugger (sorry, im pretty macro "dumb"), then its a little faster. By little, I mean 8 minutes instead of 10.  The funny thing is, I have older versions of this file and they run this macro fine. I even copied it over and still it runs slow. The only changes to this file are other macros but they dont activate until I click buttons so I don't know why  its now running slow. If I had to nail it down to an action, I think it started happening after I added this line to another macro....      On Error Resume Next

Comment: Please remove the line `On Error Resume Next` and step into each line of the code by pressing `F8` key. Note two things, 1) which lines raise errors (and what errors) and, 2) which lines take longer time to run. Then report back.

Comment: Ok, I removed the On Error Resume Next line from the other macro. It seemed to have no effect and I ended with no errors. Each line also takes about 1.5 seconds to process and I have only the one workbook open along with outlook, teams, and the browser window. I used to have A LOT more open when it would run faster so I don't think it's a hardware issue.

Comment: Also, I don't know if it's pertinent, but I do not have any macro's set up on this SHEET. All macros are in MODULES. One of my other sheets has a macro in it so that the row selected is highlighted. Yes, I know it makes it run a little slow when I have that sheet selected but it isnt a big impact.      Code i have on the OTHER sheet:  `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Application.CutCopyMode = False Then
      Application.Calculate
   End If
End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **UNTESTED**, but I hope it works and can be used for learning purposes.

I refactored part of it in order to show how to simplify a macro generated code.

Make a backup copy of your workbook before running it.

Run it by pressing `F8` key and try to check where it fails and where it may take too long

' Read the comments and specially adjust target sheet name

Some suggestions:

- Add `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules so Variables are always declared
- Separate your code into logical steps (I used sub procedures to make it more readable)
- Name your variables to something your future self or whoever maintains the code will understand

**Code:**

```
Public Sub PostSchedule()
    '

    ' Basic error handling
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    
    ' Turn off stuff
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Reference workbook, worksheet and pivot table
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Set targetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim targetsheet As Worksheet
    Set targetsheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim pivotTable1 As PivotTable
    Set pivotTable1 = targetsheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    
    
    ' Refresh source data
    pivotTable1.PivotCache.Refresh
    
    ' Clear slicers filters
    With targetWorkbook
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_1_Sun").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_2_Mon").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_3_Tue").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_4_Wed").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_5_Thu").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_6_Fri").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_7_Sat").ClearManualFilter
    End With
    
    ' Setup pivot fields
    With pivotTable1
        .PivotFields("Shift").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Shift").Position = 6
        
        .PivotFields("Trainer").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Trainer").Position = 7
        
        .PivotFields("1 Sun").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("1 Sun").Position = 8
        
        .PivotFields("2 Mon").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("2 Mon").Position = 9
        
        .PivotFields("3 Tue").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("3 Tue").Position = 10
            
        .PivotFields("4 Wed").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("4 Wed").Position = 11
        
        .PivotFields("5 Thu").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("5 Thu").Position = 12
        
        .PivotFields("6 Fri").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("6 Fri").Position = 13
            
        .PivotFields("7 Sat").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("7 Sat").Position = 14
        
        .PivotFields("LOA").Orientation = xlHidden
        .PivotFields("Present").Orientation = xlHidden
        
    End With
    
    ' Setup sheet for printing
    SetupSheet targetsheet
    
    ' Ajust slicer and print
    Dim shiftSlicer As SlicerCache
    Set shiftSlicer = targetWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift")
    AdjustAndPrint shiftSlicer, targetsheet
    
    
    ' This part you can adjust it based on the other sub samples
    DoOtherStuff
    

CleanExit:
    ' Turn on stuff
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Exit Sub
 
CleanFail:
    Debug.Print "Something went wrong: " & Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
    
End Sub

Private Sub SetupSheet(ByVal targetsheet As Worksheet)

    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    
    With targetsheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
        .PrintArea = ""
        
        ' Other page properties
        .LeftHeader = "&""-,Bold""&18&U&K02-045????&U&K09+000 Crew Sheet"
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = "&D"
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = "&P of &N"
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    
End Sub

Private Sub AdjustAndPrint(ByVal shiftSlicer As SlicerCache, ByVal targetsheet As Worksheet)

    Dim slicerItemNames As Variant
    slicerItemNames = Array("12:00:00 AM", _
                        "12:30:00 AM", _
                        "1:30:00 AM", _
                        "4:00:00 AM", _
                        "8:00:00 AM", _
                        "8:30:00 AM", _
                        "10:00:00 AM", _
                        "11:00:00 AM", _
                        "11:30:00 AM", _
                        "12:30:00 AM", _
                        "3:00:00 PM", _
                        "4:00:00 PM", _
                        "11:00:00 PM", _
                        "11:30:00 PM", _
                        "(blank)")
    
    ' Loop through items, select and print
    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = 0 To UBound(slicerItemNames)
        
        ' Skip the blank
        If slicerItemNames(counter) = "(blank)" Then Exit For
        
        ' Inner loop to select each slicer once
        Dim innerCounter As Long
        For innerCounter = 0 To UBound(slicerItemNames)
            shiftSlicer.slicerItems(slicerItemNames(counter)).Selected = (counter = innerCounter)
        Next innerCounter
        
        ' Print each iteration
        targetsheet.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
        
    Next counter

    ' Clear slicer filter
    shiftSlicer.ClearManualFilter

End Sub

Private Sub DoOtherStuff()

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("1 Sun")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 6
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("1 Sun").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("2 Mon").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("4 Wed").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("5 Thu").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("6 Fri").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("7 Sat").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("3 Tue").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Trainer")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("LOA")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 7
    End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("1 Sun")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 8
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Present")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 9
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = "&""-,Bold""&18&U&K02-045????&U&K09+000 Crew Sheet"
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = "&D"
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = "&P of &N"
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_1_Sun")
        .slicerItems("6am").Selected = True
        .slicerItems("off").Selected = False
        .slicerItems("x").Selected = True
        .slicerItems("6th").Selected = True
        .slicerItems("5th").Selected = True
        .slicerItems("PTO").Selected = True
        .slicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
    End With
End Sub
```

You're doing a lot of printing, so also check if printer communication may be affecting your macro run time.

Let me know how it goes

Comment: Ok, so right off the bat, I noticed you turned off calculations and then it dawned on me that I had recently created a very large chart with A LOT of vlookups and other calculations. That was exactly what was slowing everything down. Your script mostly worked except that it prints out all shifts, then -1, then -2, so on and so on until it gets to one shift (the 1230pm shift). Still, it led to a solution which was turning off the calculations. I'm going to incorporate that into all my scripts. I also saw you do some interesting things with your code, so I will play with that too. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome. was a long shot because I didn't have the pivot table to test it, but I'm glad it helped.